# is it possible to permanently disable "Mark item as read when selection changes"?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have a user who keeps reporting that emails are being read when they are not double clicking them. I have changed disabled "Mark item as read when selection changes" several times only for her to call me back a day or two later because it's happening again. I check the settings and sure enough "Mark item as read when selection changes" is enabled again. Is there a hotkey for this setting I am not aware of? I have been trying to google an answer but so far all I can find is articles on how to disable/enable this setting.

I have tried this registry change as well and restarted my outlook after the registry change:
[Registry Edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIxl1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the option as shown in the following figure is what you want to permanently disable?
[image]

If so, please try to disable it by registry:

1.Win+R>type regedit in the Open box, and then select OK;

2.Locate the path, if the path can't be found, please try to manually create the path and values like below::

Registry Path:

***HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Office\xx.0\Outlook\Preferences***

Value Type：   ***DWORD***

Value Name： ***previewdontmarkuntilchange***

Valued:             ***1***

(Note: The xx.0 placeholder represents your version of Office (16.0 = Office 2016, Office 365 and Office 2019, 15.0 = Office 2013))

3.Restart Outlook and check if the option have been disabled.

(It should be noted that if you modify the registry by mistake, serious problems may occur. Please [back up the registry](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows-855140ad-e318-2a13-2829-d428a2ab0692) before operation.)

Hope the above help!

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to disable. For some reason the settings keeps enabling itself or the user is unknowingly doing it. I had to create all the keys after Microsoft in the path above. I'm not sure if it worked because I can still edit the setting within outlook settings

Comment: Yes, some keys of the path need to be created manually. Do you mean that the issue will still occurs after setting this registry?

Comment: It's been two days but so far no, the issue hasn't occurred again. I was just saying that even though I added the reg key, I could still click on the check box "Mark Item as read when selection changes" within the outlook settings.

Comment: According to common sense, if you change the registry, this option will be grayed out and cannot be checked. Please contact your administrator to check whether some group policy settings affect the outlook client. If not, it is recommended that you could uninstall and reinstall outlook and then disable to check whether this option is grayed out.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Comment: Hi Christy, what you suggested did not work. There is no Group policy being applied related to oulook. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling. The setting is still getting enabled a few days after I change it within outlook.

Comment: You mean that after changing the registry, this option can be successfully grayed out, but after a few days, this option returns to its previous appearance, right? If so, have you done any special operation during this period?

Comment: no I mean it was never greyed out.

Comment: According to my tests on multiple clients, i can successfully use the registry to disable this option and gray it, which did not reproduce your problem. In order to eliminate some possible windows factors, if possible, maybe you can try to create a new windows profile(https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-a-local-user-or-administrator-account-in-windows-20de74e0-ac7f-3502-a866-32915af2a34d) on these problematic devices to check if there're any differences.

Comment: Hi Christy, I tried it on my PC and a coworkers (we are both in IT) the option was not greyed out. There's only 1 problem PC to my knowledge.

Comment: Hello again, see the image I added to the original post. I copied your registry change and steps but the option is still not greyed out. This is on my machine and not the problem machine but it's the same

Comment: Do you log in to the same account as the problem machine on your machine for testing? How about trying a few more machines?
If the problem occurs on multiple machines, the problem may be related to some unified settings or installed programs in your organization. Please try to close your antivirus software, and perform a clean boot for windows(https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows-da2f9573-6eec-00ad-2f8a-a97a1807f3dd) to check if the issue still occur.